# Free Style still renders outline on a particle emitter even if Show Emitter is unchecked

Tags: freestyle

So I have this sphere used as an particle emitter, and I made sure Show Emitter is unchecked in Render under Particle.And But when I use F12, it doesn't render the suphere, but I can see a black outline showing up at where the sphere is. 
I have Freestyle turn on FYI. Everything is rendering fine just I don't want freestyle line renderer to render my emitter.
I am not sure what to do, I am using cycle render and Blender 2.8
Thanks